# UDF calling external C++ code inside SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

Suposse I have an UDF in SQL Server 2008:

```
Create function dbo.ReadXml (@xmlMatrix xml) returns table
as
return
( select
   --SOME C++ CODE
)
go
```

- Is it possible to add a c++ code or call a c++ function inside the UDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onyl if this C++ function was compiled and installed as an [extended stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164716%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).
But extended stored procedures are deprecated and will be removed soon.

So your only reliable option is to write a [CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131102.aspx). It can be a C# CLR function that calls an external C++ dll, or it might be a managed C++ CLR function that would contain your code directly.

Comment: Ok, so the steps would be:   -  To have a C# CLR function   -  This C# function calls external C++ dll....  How would that C# call a C++ dll? I don't undestand well that step...

Comment: @cMinor By using the [DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx).

Comment: As you answered, What do you recommend, C# CLR Function, or managed C++ Function?

Comment: @cMinor Whatever is easier for you to use/maintain. For me it would be easier to have a separate C++ dll, as I'm way too unfamiliar with managed C++. However, having a single managed C++ assembly has an advantage of requiring the lowest permissions (`SAFE`) because you don't try to load something from outside.